# Related posts by category not working right

Tags: posts, categories

I have somehow managed to create this code to display Related Posts by category on single post page.

```
<div class="relatedposts">
 <h3>You might also like</h3>
      <?php
        $orig_post = $post;
        global $post; 
        $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);

        if ($categories) {

          $category_ids = array();
          foreach($categories as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;

          $args=array(
            'category__in' => $category_ids,
            'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
            'showposts'=> 4, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
            'caller_get_posts'=>1);

          $my_query = new wp_query( $args );
          while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
           $my_query->the_post();
      ?> 

       <div class="relatedthumb">
              <a rel="external" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title ="<?php the_title(); ?>" ><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?><br /><?php the_title(); ?></a>
       </div>

      <?php } // ending while loop
       }

$post = $orig_post;
wp_reset_query();
?>
</div>
```

Problem is, this code doesn't displays related posts of the same category as on single post page. Even includes the same post displayed on single post page and also shows some recent posts.

You can test yourself. Please suggest how can I resolve this or am I missing some thing in this code?

Thanks

Comment: And what DOES it display? PS. You should use `posts_per_page` and not `showposts` param (the latter one is deprecated).

Comment: sometimes category unrelated, sometimes recent and some category related all in  4 posts.

Comment: Do you call this inside loop?

Comment: No, this is shown after post content

Comment: Are you sure that global `$post` has correct value, when you call this code? It can be changed by some other part of code (so $post is not the post which content is displayed)...

Comment: I actually, saw in one snippet, but I really don't know real use of global $post variable.